# mysql keyword search using full text

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to do keyword search using full text below is my current code.

```
SELECT id, name
              FROM masterpages 
              WHERE MATCH nameAGAINST ('" . $searchTerm . "' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND pageId = $pageID 
          ORDER BY pageOrder
              LIMIT $limit
```

I want to search with searchterm priority

If I do search "do" is should come the results to order which search term postion.
Ex: downloads, random => downloads should come first because "do" is in first position.

But above search is not giving results, advicep pls

Comment: full text search don't work with short string

Comment: @scaisEdge is there any alternative ways ? LIKE ? pls advice

Comment: yes  ..you can use like but like work only one column for each  condition  ..